# Sticky header on scroll up, but compensate for initial absolute positioning

Tags: jquery, css-position, fixed

I'm having trouble modifying this sticky nav code to fit some slightly different circumstances. Here's the source: [Codepen link](https://codepen.io/bravotanmoy/pen/zBNPYV)

And here is what I've done so far: [jsfiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/vu7cr4qf/2/)

Mine is different in that there may (or may not be - important) a top bar above the header, but it's not part of the sticky header, so it won't be visible unless you've scrolled back up to the top.

I'm trying to modify the jQuery to compensate for the following:
1) The header has to fix itself into position below the alert bar (if present) when the scroll reaches back to the top.
2) The header can't be fixed initially, it has to scroll off the screen normally  like a static header.  It should only slide up out of view when the user scrolls down from somewhere other than the very top of the page. 
3) The animations need to be smooth , there can't be any flickering or jumping when the user scrolls back to the top of the page.

Number 3 is the problem with my code. If you scroll up close to the top, then do the last 100px or so by clicking the scrollbar arrow instead of using the mouse wheel, you can see when it goes back to absolute position from fixed, and the header suddenly "jumps" back into position.

I know the height of the alert bar, if present, needs to be accounted for (to know when the initial scroll from top has gone past the height of the alert bar and header), but everywhere I try to add it in to the calculations makes the jumping worse or breaks the effect altogether.

Edit: Also, I'm sure the delta value in there is incorrect, I'm not really sure what to do with that. I thought the delta should be the height of the alert bar and the header combined but that didn't work.

```
<script>
// Hide Header on on scroll down
var didScroll;
var lastScrollTop = 0;
var delta = 30;
var navbarHeight = $('header').outerHeight();

if($('alertBar').length) {
  var alertHeight = $('alertBar').outerHeight();
} else {
  var alertHeight = 0;
}

$(window).scroll(function(event){
  didScroll = true;
});

setInterval(function() {
  if (didScroll) {
    hasScrolled();
    didScroll = false;
  }
}, 50);

function hasScrolled() {
  var st = $(this).scrollTop();

  // Make sure they scroll more than delta
  if(Math.abs(lastScrollTop - st) <= delta)
  return;

  // If they scrolled down and are past the navbar, add class .nav-up.
  // This is necessary so you never see what is "behind" the navbar.
  if (st > lastScrollTop && st > navbarHeight) {
    // Scroll Down, hide nav
    $('header').removeClass('nav-down').addClass('nav-up');
  } else {
    // Scroll Up, show nav
    if(st + $(window).height() < $(document).height()) {
      $('header').removeClass('nav-up').addClass('nav-down not-top');
      $('body').css({"padding-top": navbarHeight});
    }
    // if scrolled up to the top again
    if(st <= navbarHeight) {
      $('header').removeClass('not-top');
      $('body').css({"padding-top": "0px"})
    }


  }

  lastScrollTop = st;
}

</script>
```

Basically, I'm trying to smooth out the transition when the user gets back to the top and the header goes back into position below the alert bar. Anyone have an idea?

Comment: When you scroll back up you're checking the value of `navbarHeight` but instead you should wait until you reach the position of `alertHeight` and then start showing the alert bar. I'd make `alertHeight` a global-scope (window) variable too like `navbarHeight` so you can use it in the rest of your code.

Comment: That makes the jump worse and when you scroll back to the top, sometimes the alert bar ends up underneath the header instead of above: https://jsfiddle.net/oLxkhdub/

Comment: Indeed... clearly some other changes are also required. ;)

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE**

https://jsfiddle.net/7mgt5eku/3/

you will need to add navbar class to header, like so...

`<header class = "nav-down navbar">`

and add this to css

`.nav-down.hidden {
    transition:all 0.2s;
  }`

Let me know what you think.

---

You can spruce this up with variables and delays if you feel it's necessary, but I think this will give you what you're looking for...

```
    $(window).scroll(function(event){
  didScroll = true;
  if($(document).scrollTop() < 30 && $('#alertBar').length){
    $('.nav-down').css('top', "2.5rem");
  } else{
    $('.nav-down').css('top', $(document).scrollTop())
  }

});
```

Sorry, missed the "checking when alert is gone, the " && $('#alertBar').length" should take care of that.

Comment: And ditch the rest of your js. This works with current css and HTML found on your fiddle page. And obviously, if you want, you can make the stop point dynamic, based upon the alert's actual height.

Comment: I don't think I've implemented your change correctly. It makes the header always stick to the top instead of only when scrolling upwards, and header appears to bounce down the screen when you scroll back to the top: https://jsfiddle.net/oLxkhdub/3/

Comment: Oh, I must have missed the part about it only showing on scroll. Give me a sec. I think it can still be done rather simply.

Comment: I think I'm getting close, I just need to dial in the scroll up part, it's a little hacky right now because it just pops in, take a loop.
https://jsfiddle.net/7mgt5eku/

Comment: Ok, check this out! I think this is very close to what you're looking for!

Comment: I think the jumping problem has something to do with the transition. I don't have it saved anymore but I tried adding the transition only after the initial scroll down past the header, and other similar idea, to no avail.

Comment: You forgot the link!

Comment: did an update instead. obviously the javascript you'll have to get from fiddle, but i pointed out the html css updates because they could have easily been missed.
and, of course, you can get rid of the console.log's, just needed them for debugging.

Comment: Thanks but it still seems pretty jittery when you scroll up, and there's no transition, it just suddenly appears in place.

Comment: even on the new link posted in the answer? Because it is super smooth on my screen. What browser are you using? Older or newer computer? Scroll related animations are the most tasking on a processor unfortunately.

Comment: try this one, lol, 
https://jsfiddle.net/7mgt5eku/3/
the transition is much different. smooth as butter compared to the first one

Comment: Nice, yes that's a lot smoother. Thank you! There's still a little bit of a jitter or flash when scrolling up, it doesn't quite stay perfectly fixed. I'm tinkering with it now.

Comment: \m/ nice. that's awesome. try removing the console.log's and updating the parseint line to: (parseInt($('.navbar').css('top'), 10)) - the ,10 makes the numbers more precise. Although, (idk about you) but I only seem to have the flicker issue when using the scroll bar, and fast. But normal scrolling and the up and down arrows are smooth. Good luck man. I'm passin' out.

Comment: Thanks so much for the help! I think I can get it, it's so close.